# Hold neural network distribution nearly constant to help training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a neural network $F(X)$ which outputs $Y$. The output $Y$ goes to another separate neural network $G(X)$ and is used as a label training example. I minimize $min{(G(X)-F(X))^2}$. The output of both networks is unconstrained and real valued. Additionally, $G(X)$ is not updated at the same moment as $F(X)$, but is fixed during training of $G(X)$. $F(X)$ is trained separately, with a different objective and loss function (which I can't publish here).

I have noticed that the second network struggles, because the first network changes distribution of outputs very often. How could I enforce or restrain the first network $F(X)$, to not change the distribution so much ?

Comment: The description is a bit unclear. Do you minimize the squared difference between the outputs of two neural networks? Why? What is $X$ and $x$? You mention $Y$ that is not used anywhere. What does $min(\cdot)^2$ mean, it's the smallest value that gets squared?

Comment: @Tim To make output of one neural network as similar as possible to the output of the other network. It's a similar setting as in GAN's discriminator, though it's not GAN. Furthermore, weights of $F(X)$ are not updated at the same moment, they're fixed through training of $G(X)$